# How to do JMX over JMS?

Tags: java, jms, apache-camel, jmx

I need to enhance the JMX interfaces of a distributed java application. The reason for choosing JMX is the simplicity of exposing data. These distributed apps exist in several different machines connected to a JMS server (activemq 5.7) (which in turn is connected to another JMS server to bridge 2 networks, also activemq 5.7).

What I would like to do, is to be able to access the remote JMX interfaces on the individual servers from anywhere on the JMS network. I would nee full JMX access as if accessing through the usual RMI interface. That means every type of action.

I understand I could use [lingo](http://lingo.codehaus.org/JMX+over+JMS) to make the remote jmx interfaces talk to the JMS server, and from there my bridge should allow me access to them (assuming its configured correctly).

Is this a good approach? has anyone tried lingo for this purpose? Are there other options out there I may have not found?

A plan B could be to use apache camel RMI module, but it seems like if lingo is an option, it will be much more plug & play than this.

Comment: UPDATE: I integrated lingo with great success. I now have every JMX mbean exposed to the JMS network so anything that can connect to it, has access to JMX endpoints in any other system, and lingo also provides a "public" topic so events can be spied on without consuming messages for the real handlers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's not a bad way to go. The one downside of using JMS that I can think of, off the top of my head, is the [dependency on a broker](http://www.zeromq.org/whitepapers%3abrokerless), which most JMS implementations rely on.

On the other hand, it does present some interesting capabilities like discovery, asynchronous JMX invocation and pub/sub multicast style JMX operations where you could issue one operation request and receive back a response from all your MBeanServers.

I am not aware of any actual implementations, but it's probably not too difficult to implement. You simply need a configured client on each target JVM that will:

1. Listen for JMX requests: The listener will unmarshall the request (which should be an encoding of an [MBeanServerConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/management/MBeanServerConnection.html) method invocation). Use a common topic for pub/sub style invocations, returning the marshalled result 
   to the destination specified in the [JMSReplyTo](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/jms/Message.html#getJMSReplyTo%28%29) property in the request message. Otherwise, you could allocate a queue per JVM, or pick a unique identifier for each JVM and use message selectors.
2. If you want to implement JMX notifications, you will need to implement a proxy [NotificationListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/management/NotificationListener.html) that registers for the desired notifications and forwards them to the designated JMS destination on receipt.

You may also consider implementing a full blown [javax.management.remote](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/management/remote/package-summary.html) implementation which may integrate more smoothly into your environment by virtue of the standard adherence.

I have found the [OpenDMK](http://opendmk.java.net/) project very useful for extending/implementing JMX servers and clients. The library provides the basic building blocks for implementing a standard JMX remoting solution using a "custom" protocol. Basically, you implement a [javax.management.remote.generic.MessageConnection](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/glassfish/embedded/glassfish-embedded-all/3.0-b53/glassfish-embedded-all-3.0-b53.jar!/javax/management/remote/generic/MessageConnection.class?classDetails=ok) which serves as the transport and invocation mechanism. All JMX invocations, responses and callbacks are serialized
into instances of [javax.management.remote.message.Message,](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/glassfish/embedded/glassfish-embedded-all/3.0-b53/glassfish-embedded-all-3.0-b53.jar!/javax/management/remote/message/Message.class?classDetails=ok) and they're all Serializable so you should not have any issues writing them into and reading them from JMS [ObjectMessage](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/jms/ObjectMessage.html)s.

A couple of additional benefits you will get from this approach are:

1. Provided you configiure the classpath correctly, you should be able to connect to your JVMs using any standard JMX tool such as JConsole.
2. The OpenDMK also provides the ability to federate MBeanServers which makes all your MBeanServer instances appear, and be accessible through one central MBeanServer. This feature requires a standard JMX remoting 
   implementation.
3. The OpenDMK also implements an interesting service discovery protocol, and it comes in a couple of different flavours including raw multicast and a "phone-home" approach which would mesh nicely with your JMS protocol.

I posted a mavenised project of the OpenDMK [here](https://github.com/nickman/OpenDMK) if you're interested.

I am implementing a basic JMX client for java-agents using netty, and it optionally supports asynchronous JMX requests. Responses are delivered through a registered listener which is like a "reverse" MBeanServerConnection. In case this is useful, find the source [here](https://github.com/nickman/apmrouter/blob/master/apmrouter-agent/src/main/java/org/helios/apmrouter/jmx/mbeanserver/AsynchJMXResponseListener.java).

Comment: The central broker dependency is not a problem for me as the apps in question already exist in production and its proven to work as desired. The apps mostly "phone home" rather than talk to each other. Thanks for the suggestion of using OpenDMK. I't has come up when looking for answers but before committing to writing something at that level I would like to completely rule out the possibility of a simpler already available solution.

Answer (score 2):

Jolokia (http://www.jolokia.org/) is also a great project for remote accessing JMX using REST and JSON. It does this automatic for you. And support batch operations as well.
I suggest to take a look at that.

If you use JMX to get AMQ statistics then it offers a plugin, so you can just using JMS messaging to get the stats instead of JMX: http://activemq.apache.org/statisticsplugin.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It doesn't solve my problem as I'm not guaranteed that the "clients" will be able to expose a network port for inbound traffic but I'll definitely look into jolokia. Looks interesting.

Answer (score 0):

I would use JMS to discover the URLs of the servers I am interested in and use plain JMX from then on.  I don't see the advantage of sending every RMI call over JMS.

Comment: unfortunately network access to the RMI port is not guaranteed.

Comment: I assume you have access via JMS as it's something they have to allow already.

Comment: the clients have free outbound access, my problem is enabling RMI inbound on the clients (which is not permitted).